# PLINK change character set translation to UTF-8 (utf8)

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, putty, plink

Does anyone know how to configure the character set translation on plink ([the command line version of Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) to UTF-8? I'm trying to SSH to a Linux server whose character set configuration is UTF-8.

This can be easily achieved via Putty, but I can't seem to find that command line option on Plink...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find an option because plink doesn't do the character set translation - that's handled by the windows command window.  To change the windows command window's character set translation before you start plink use the command "chcp".

To get utf-8, you'll need to first change the console window's font to "Lucida Console".  Then, try "chcp 65001".

One caveat - I've found that there's something incredibly slow and inefficient about the windows console when it's doing utf-8 such that if you send data too quickly, plink will blow up and say "A device attached to the system is not functioning".

However, I have to ask - why are you doing this?  You should be using putty for anything interactive and for anything non-interactive, if you're redirecting output into a file the translation that the windows console has in effect at the time doesn't matter.  The file is then in utf-8, and whatever windows program you're opening it in needs to be told that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - last week a coworker of mine also informed me of the fact that the translation piece is handled by the window containing the redirected plink data. 

As to why am I doing this to being with - I'm using plink to ssh to a linux server from visual studio's build command line (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx). Effectively redirecting gcc make output from the linux machine over to VS' debugger window. In other words, using VS as a an IDE and the Linux server for compiling C++ code. chcp 65001 in VS didn't work - had to change the default local on Linux to POSIX

Comment: (PS. Tim means default locale) I had this problem doing a similar thing in Eclipse.  I solved it by inserting `export LC_ALL="POSIX";` before my `make all` command -- `export LC_ALL="POSIX"; make all`

Answer (score 2):

You could also configure a PuTTY session as desired and load it via plink:

```
plink.exe -load my_session -l my_user_name -pw my_password <your command>
```